# joomla blog layout

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

when I use a blog layout, when I hover over any content, I see a backgound with code #EEE

when I change to single article layout, hovering over the article does not show the background

I am trying to figure out what is causing the issue with hover on the blog layout.  I do not want a hover.

I checked the template css, and could not find any code that sets a backround-image or background- color on hover that has the color of #EEE

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you use another template, is the background color #EEE still there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `<head>` tag for CSS files other than `template.css` - most Joomla! templates use multiple CSS files. If you have multiple CSS files you could just search each one for a `hover` tag.

If that fails, right click the content in the blog layout using a modern browser and select the "Inspect Element" menu item that will launch a document inspector, allowing you to trace back all of the CSS etc that is affecting that element. (You will need either [Firefox+Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/html), [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html) or [Google Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html), or if you must IE8+).

On the right hand side of the document inspector you will see all the matched CSS with reference to which CSS file it is in, from there you should be able to track it down.